# .class:first-child CSS not working

Tags: html, css

Hi there I've got 4 divs each with a class called `.section` and the first div, I want to use less padding.

If you check out this codepen, I've got a [really basic example](https://codepen.io/moletek/pen/ZWjqRg) where it actually works.

However if you look at my current project, I can't actually add the `:last-child` psuedo element. Please [take a look here](https://codepen.io/moletek/pen/jqpezX) This code pen has the identical code in the CSS section. However it's not taking effect.

**HTML**

```
<div id="sermon-details" class="section">...</div>
<div id="media-content" class="section">...</div>
<div id="social-share" class="section">...</div>
<div id="advanced-settings" class="section">...</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.section:first-child{
  padding-top:15px !important; //Not applying
}
```

Please put my mind to rest! Thanks!

Comment: What class you need to target the last-child in your project?

Comment: Please include the minimal ("[mcve]") code to reproduce your problem in the body of your question.

Comment: There isn't a first-of-class selector in standard CSS

Comment: But it works in the first codepen? Therefore can I use a div as the selector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a syntax error in your project's codepen.

**Wrong**

```
.section :first-child{
  padding-top:15px !important;
}
```

**Correct (:first-child without space before)**

```
.section:first-child{
  padding-top:15px !important;
}
```

You will notice the `<h1>` tag will move according to the padding-top being applied.

-

## Alternative solution

You can add a new class to that specific section you need to apply the padding-top rule.

HTML

```
<!-- first of .section class --> 
<div class="section new-class"> 
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
.section.new-class { padding-top: 15px }
```

Comment: Yes, that's not working or changing the `<h1>`

Comment: @JonahM in case you need to target a specific class, I think the most simple solution to avoid problems is assigning a new class to that specific section and apply the rules to the new class.

Answer (score 0):

it works in first code pen cause it have a well written CSS

in second codepen - unworkable cause... awful html, awful css (imho - too many random classes and id's). U must clean your code before test for 1st element, see that css

```
.section{color: red;}/*to mark red all section classes*/

.section:first-child{
  padding-top:0px !important;
color: blue;/*to mark first child, what not exist*/
}


#sermon-details/*don't use other, unnecessary rules*/
```

to see what you have in your html!

p.s. RTFM